# Extracting filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have three datasets:

- one, df1, is built by selecting all rows having label = 1;
- one, df2, is built by selecting all rows having `Fact` = 1 (regardless label, which would be 0);
- another one, df, is the original dataset where the two datasets above come from.

**df1**

```
User Label Fact Date
321    1    0   28-04
312    1    0   22-02
315    1    0   21-12
...
```

**df2**

```
User Label Fact Date
21     0    1   18-04
532    0    1   02-01
135    0    1   22-12
...
```

**df**

```
User Label Fact Date
321    1    0   28-04
312    1    0   22-02
315    1    0   21-12
...
21     0    1   18-04
532    0    1   02-01
135    0    1   22-12
...
241    0    0   21-12
54     0    0   23-11
...
```

I would like to know how to 'extract' the dataset having `Label=0 and Fact = 0` using join.
Since I am interested in the condition `Label=0 and Fact = 0` I could use just a logical condition to extract the rows, but I am curious about possible alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the expected output. _I would like to know how to 'extract' the dataset having Label=0 and value = 0 using join._ Why a join?

Comment: sorry, it was Fact, not value. I would like to consider other alternatives to extract rows.

Comment: `df = df[(df['Label'] == 0) & (df['Fact'] == 0)]`

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any better alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[(df["Label"]==0) & (df["Fact"]==0)]` should give you what you want, or also `df2[df2["Label"]==0]`. But what did you mean by possible alternatives?

Comment: Thanks @Jack Roberts. Yes, I was extracting the rows as you did. With 'possibile alternatives' I mean the use of extracting rows considering one dataset and subtracting (or just calculating the difference) another one. I thought it was join, maybe I am wrong. For example: from the original dataset, to get the remaining rows, I should remove rows from both df1 and df2. This would give me the same rows as you did

Comment: You could try `pd.merge(d1, d2, how="inner", left_index=True, right_index=True)`, assuming each "User" ID appears only once in each dataframe and it's the index (use `d1.set_index("User", inplace=True)` if not). But I think extracting them as above is the right thing to do in this case.